# Data not inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I tried inserting html form values into the database but it is not executing. i could not figure out exactly what the issue might be. I have run mysql error testing to check what might be causing it but it didn't display anything.

Here is the insert syntax:

```
<?php

    require_once('../includes/config.php'); 

    if (isset($_POST['add_user'])) {

        $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

                $location="uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                $name = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
                $gender=strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender']));
                $uname=strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
                $ut=strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_type']));
                $pass=strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
                $salt = sha1('_wchs2242%..father%/**...mygreenparrot_password&username\--\__/heelo"@@@@@@.');
                $password = md5($pass.$salt);
                $status=strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']));

        if(empty($name) || empty($uname) || empty($pass)){
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<div class="alert-error"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span> Please check your inputs for missing values.</div>';  
        header('Location: add_member');

        }
        elseif(!empty($uname)){
        $query = "SELECT username FROM panel_users WHERE username = '$uname'";  
            $chk = mysql_query($query);
            if(mysql_num_rows($chk) > 0){
                $_SESSION['error']  = '<div class="alert-error"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span> The username you entered already exist in the database. please input another one</div>'; 
                header('Location: add_member');
            }
        }

        elseif(!empty($name) && !empty($uname) && !empty($pass)){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

                $save="INSERT INTO panel_users (name, gender, user_type, username, password, status, pic) VALUES('$name','$gender', '$ut','$uname','$password','$status','$location')";
                $sate = mysql_query($save);

                if($sate == true){
                $_SESSION['success']  = '<div class="alert-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-checked"></span> Saved!</div>';    
                header('Location: add_member');
                exit;
                }
                else{
                echo $_SESSION['error'] = '<div class="alert-error"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span> Failed! Please try again.</div>';    
                header('Location: add_member');
                exit;
                }

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Mandatory "don't use mysql_* functions" comment.  At a minimum use mysqli and please remember to protect yourself from SQL injection

Comment: use `password_hash` to hash your passwords. Do not use `md5`

Comment: start fresh this is to bad to just be fixed

Comment: your if else statements look weird to be honest

Comment: you're outputting before header in the last `else`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a uselessly weak hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Do I even want to know what that "salt" is? There's utter voodoo going on there. That is not even close to a cryptographically secure salt.

Answer (score 0):

1- You are using an old mysql so please convert your work to mysqli because from php 7 and on, mysql has been stopped completely.

2- use this check to catch the error and see:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error<br />".mysql_error());
```

3- The if conditions are not logically arranged. better to design and then start coding. and please don't be so hurry so you mostly forget many pieces and make many holes in your code.

- First decide what condition for allowing execution and make it first.
- Then keep the other conditions after. that will clear your code for later maintenance and make you really feel satisfied and more performing.

Best wishes to you.

Comment: Alright guys. Thank you all for your help and suggestions. I will make corrections right away.